# Test Google search page

Tags: ruby, cucumber, webrat

I'm studying webrat and cucumber and trying to create simple example. Here is my feature file:

```
Scenario: Searching for something
    Given I have opened "http://www.google.com/"
    When I search for "some text"
```

Here is my step definitions:

```
Given /^I have opened "([^\"]*)"$/ do |url|
  visit url
end

When /^I search for "([^\"]*)"$/ do |query|
  fill_in "q", :with => query
  click_button "Google Search"
end
```

When I am running the tests I get error message:

> Could not find field: "q" (Webrat::NotFoundError)

If I'll comment 'fill_in'-line I get other error message:

> Could not find button "Google Search" (Webrat::NotFoundError)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that Webrat is not following the redirect from www.google.com to your locale specific Google site ([for details on redirect](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=873)). For example, since I am in Canada, going to www.google.com will redirect me to www.google.ca. As a result, when I use Webrat to visit www.google.com I see a '302 Moved' page. Since webrat does not follow the redirect to the search page, you do not have access to the text field 'q'.

I would try the `save_and_open_page` method to check what page you actually ended up on. You can run the following script (and then open the file it creates) as a quick check:

```
require "mechanize"
require 'webrat'
include Webrat::Matchers
include Webrat::Methods

Webrat.configure {|c| c.mode = :mechanize} 
begin
    visit('http://www.google.com/')   #=> 
    fill_in "q", :with => 'some text'
    click_button "Google Search"
rescue
    save_and_open_page 
end
```

If you are ending up on the '302 Moved' page like I was, then you can add the following after the visit:

```
click_link "here"
```